# Testing code inside a ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: testing, mocking, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a ScheduledExecutorService set up to update some objects every few minutes.

I am trying to test whether or not the update is occurring and of course some edge cases.

```
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(()-> {
    //Code to update objects
}, 0, 4, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

I was wondering how would I go about testing and maybe mocking this so I don't have to depend on Thread.sleep

Answer (score 0):

Note the `scheduleAtFixedRate` method returns a `Future`, so you should not use `Thread.sleep`, but one of the `Future#get` methods.

Another suggestion is to replace the hard-coded time delay (4 minutes) with a configurable parameter, so you can change it from a test.